# bluetoothgatt onCharacteristicWrite return with status code 6 with ble device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to write to a characteristic of a BLE device. According to the documentation, the characteristic is capable of read and write, with different usages. I was already successful with reading from it but i am having some problems with write. Every time i try to write to it the onWriteCharacterstic function arrives with a status code 6, which is supposed to be GATT_REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED.

I am not really sure what can cause it. I added all the necessary bluetooth permission to my app, and the documentation states that it is capable of write.

My code looks somewhat like this (simplified):

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered( BluetoothGatt gatt, int status ){
    if( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ){
        mGatt = gatt;
        mService= gatt.getService(UUID_SERVICE);
        mChar = mService.getCharacteristic(UUID_CHAR);
        byte[] value = {...}
        mChar.setValue(value);
        boolean retval = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(mChar); //retval is true
    }
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
{
... //status here is 6
}
```

I also made some check with the functions getProperties() and getPermissions() for the characteristic. The getPermissions() function returns 0, which i couldn't match to anything in the android documentation, and the getProperties() returns 10, which is also weird. With properties it would mean that it supports notifications, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it was a problem with the phone. After it had it's bluetooth turned off for a few hours it worked correctly.